# How do I store XML data in a database on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xml

The idea for my project is : retrieve announcements from my website to my iPhone app (using XML file),then I want to make the users of my app can select any announcement he want and click button in ActionSheet which moves the selected announcement to "favorite announcements tableview" (have Database for favorite announcements)
*"as apple done in favorite contacts in phone app for iPhone ".*

So, I want to copy some of this data to specific database in my app (and display in tableview) , can I do this? how? any hints?

thanks..

Comment: Ok, thanks.But do not have any answer?

Comment: hi Alex, thank you for edit the title to be clear, and I hope you to help me.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite sounds like the way to go, it's a very simple lightweight database for which you can find many tutorials online to get started.

You would have to create the database, usually on the first app launch (and no other time after that).  When they click the action button the function tied to the button would retrieve the data and insert it into the database, and the favorite screen would retrieve the data from the database to populate it's table (assuming you do want it in tableview form that is).  Long story short, a google search for 'sqlite iphone' should get you started.